# Group Z, find<m,n>

Tags: abstract-algebra

How to find <8,14>, in group Z under addition,  Any integer k such that the subgroup is . For 8, <8>={8n : n$\in$Z}, <14>={14n:n$\in$Z}, so <8,14>={22n and 6n:n$\in$Z}, is it right? how to get k?

Comment: It is not right, note that $2$ is in the subgroup, and all elements are even, so the subgroup is the group generated by $2$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $8$ and $14$ are multiples of $2$, $<8,14>$ is contained in $<2>$. On the other hand, since $2 = 1\cdot 14 + (-2)\cdot 8$, $2\in <8,14>$, and thus $<2>$ is contained in $<8,14>$. Therefore, $<8,14> = <2>$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $l=\gcd(m,n)$. I will prove that $\langle l \rangle= \langle m,n \rangle$.This is relevant to your question, and is the general case which is similar to kobe's answer. I will complete the proof by showing both $\langle l \rangle \subseteq \langle m,n \rangle$ and $\langle m,n \rangle \subseteq \langle l \rangle$. First suppose $a \in \langle l \rangle$. Bezout's identitly allows $a=kl=sm+tn$. Therefore $a \in \langle m,n \rangle$. Next, consider $b\in\langle m,n \rangle$. Notice that $l$ can be factored from both $m$ and $n$. $b=qm+pn=l(qm'+pn')$. Hence, $b$ is a multiple of $l$. As a result $b \in \langle l \rangle$. So $\langle m,n \rangle \subseteq \langle l \rangle$.

QED

Answer (score -2):

Look for the GCD for the  you know that if GCD (a, b)=m then both numbers are multiples of m and hence can be put in the cyclic group of . 
If GCD(a,b)= 1 i.e. the numbers are coprime then there exists a linear combination for numbers such that ax+by=1 therefore i can make 1 to be any integer i want and hence the entire set of Integers

Comment: use LaTeX please.